# How to adjust statusline height in MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I just installed powerline for mvim. It works fine except my statusline is a bit too big which makes it look weird:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you have large spacing between _all_ lines, not just the statusline. Does `:set linespace=0` help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have large spacing between all lines, not just the statusline. That can be controlled via the `'linespace'` option.

```
:set linespace=0
```

reduces the additional spacing to none. Since this is the default, find the place where this got changed (via `:verbose set linespace?`), and remove that, or add the above to your `.gvimrc`.